# DB2 select from final table update gives SQL0199 error

Tags: db2, iseries

Goal: I am trying to retrieve records that were affected by `UPDATE` query.

Based on [IBMs article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0011133.html) I can use the following query:

```
SELECT empno, salary FROM FINAL TABLE
(UPDATE employee SET salary = salary * 1.10 WHERE job = 'CLERK')
```

However when I try to run similar query in database I get the following error:

`[42601][-199] [SQL0199] Keyword UPDATE not expected. Valid tokens: INSERT.`

Comment: You might want to indicate your Db2 for IBM i version (and reference documentation for that platform, not LUW).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Db2 for i 7.2 Knowledge Center, shows that only `INSERT`'s are valid in `data-change-table-reference`s, not `UPDATE`'s

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafztabref.htm

```
data-change-table-reference

|----+-FINAL-+--TABLE--(--INSERT statement--)--+--------------------+----|
     '-NEW---'                                 '-correlation-clause-'
```

> If a data-change-table-reference is specified, the intermediate result table is the set of rows inserted by the INSERT statement.

The link you referenced in your original question is for DB2 for LUW (Linux, Unix and Windows) 9.7. This is essentially a different product than Db2 for i.

Comment: Thank you. This makes more sense now