# How can I lock row for reading/updating in DB2?

Tags: db2, iseries, db2-midrange

I am trying to resolve a race condition in my application.

I have a table that is used as a work queue and many threads and read/update it. The following query is executed from application. First it reads the ID's of available jobs, then it reserves them and gets the info.

```sql
SELECT ID FROM JOBS WHERE LOCKED_BY IS NULL LIMIT 5; --Check available jobs
UPDATE JOBS LOCKED_BY = 'Thread#1' WHERE ID IN (?); --Lock jobs
SELECT * FROM JOBS WHERE ID IN(?); --Get info about jobs to process
```

Issue arises when multiple threads go at this table at the same time. This if happens if `'Thread#2'` reads the row before `'Thread#1'` runs the `UPDATE`. Causing same jobs to run twice.

I have found a solution by wrapping the queries in:

```sql
LOCK TABLE JOBS;
--Queries from above
COMIT;
```

This works fine and prevents race conditions but it is a bit extreme, because threads have to wait for each other to finish.

How can I make sure that I can place a lock only on records from the following query?

```sql
SELECT ID FROM JOBS WHERE LOCKED_BY IS NULL LIMIT 5;
```

This is on AS400 DB2 database, now LUW

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you're looking for a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` pattern with [Isolation RR](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/perf/src/tpc/db2z_isorr.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using a table?  The IBM i provides a native data queue object...

If your application is running off platform in a language that doesn't offer direct access to the native objects, you could always build a stored procedure or user defined function on the I to provide access to the data queue.

Having said that, the answer to your question is the same for any RDBMS, use [isolation levels.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzisol.htm)

In your case, you want to use *Read Stability*

> Like level RR, level Read Stability (RS) ensures that:
>
> Any row read during a unit of work is not changed by other activation
>   groups that use different commitment definitions until the unit of
>   work is complete. 1 Any row changed (or a row that is currently locked
>   with an UPDATE row lock) by another activation group using a different
>   commitment definition cannot be read until it is committed.

Simply add `WITH RS` to your statements...

```
SELECT ID FROM JOBS WHERE LOCKED_BY IS NULL WITH RS LIMIT 5
UPDATE JOBS LOCKED_BY = 'Thread#1' WHERE ID IN (?) WITH RS
COMMIT
```

The first statement will lock (up to) 5 rows..till the `COMMIT` is done.

Note that the table will need to be journaled if it is not already.

Comment: I wrapped the calls in transaction with rs locks. Seems to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to locking (running with RS isolation will still have threads wait for each other and possibly deadlock, unless you `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE`), if you can tolerate processing less than 5 jobs at a time, you can use an optimistic approach:

```
UPDATE JOBS LOCKED_BY = 'Thread#1' WHERE ID IN (?) AND LOCKED_BY IS NULL; --Lock jobs
SELECT * FROM JOBS WHERE ID IN(?) AND LOCKED_BY = 'Thread#1'; --Get info
```

Comment: I tried doing a similar thing, using `SELECT FROM FINAL TABLE`  https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/232659  but update is not supported in my version of DB